# Azure, receive notification if web app is stopped or down

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

How can I configure Azure to send me notifications if WebApp is stopped or failed to start? a email will suffice. Thanks.

Comment: well explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-overview) on the Azure Portal/WebApp blade, but I'd recommend you to use Azure Monitor to [configure alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/tutorial-alert) using Application Insights if you need more configuration options.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create an [`Alert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-overview) with the condition and action group as mentioned below.

[image]

I know martin's answer is correct, but i just wanted to mention the exact condition for the alert.